# How to break links in OLEFormat object?

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint 2007 slide with two embedded Excel objects.
I want to access the sheet1 tab and break all links.
I was trying to copy and paste by value. Although the code runs, it does nothing.

```vb
Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSheet As Object
Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
 
For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes

        ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide oSl.SlideIndex
        If oSh.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            oSh.OLEFormat.Activate

            With oSh.OLEFormat.Object
               .Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy
               .Application.Workbooks(1).Worksheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End With

            ActiveWindow.Selection.Unselect
            ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide oSl.SlideIndex

        End If
    
    Next
    
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated/edited ... skip the Application update line, try like so instead:

```
If oSh.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
    With oSh.OLEFormat.Object   ' added .Object here
        .Activate
        .Application.workbooks(1).worksheets(2).Cells.Copy
        .Application.workbooks(1).worksheets(2).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End With
End if
```

First, either define a constant lxPasteValues As Long = -4163 or replace xlPasteValues with -4163 in the code above.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, but I tried it and I just got the "Object doesn't support property or method" Error.

Comment: I replaced the copy and paste lines with this one and it works                                                                  .Worksheets(1).Range("A1:a312").Value = .Workbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:a312").Value

Comment: Sorry @Steve, but that code doesn't open the embedded object, doesn't copy or paste anything either.   It may work in Excel, but not i Powerpoint VBA.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn't work for you ... tested it here (in PowerPoint 2010) and it does the trick.

Comment: Maybe we have two different objects.  Mine is a excel.sheet.8 object.  If you have 2010, I bet yours is a excel.sheet.12 object and these two objects are not the same.   Thanks for your input.

Comment: I finally got it to work   
 
If oSh.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then             oSh.OLEFormat.Activate
  
 With oSh.OLEFormat.Object

        .Worksheets(1).Cells.Copy
        .Worksheets(1).Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=-4163